# jQuery Validation Method Phone number begin with plus mark

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have written this method to validate phone begin with **plus** mark but it doesn't work, can someone please explain the issue thank you all,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("fnType", function (phone_number, element) {
phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
return this.optional(element) ||  phone_number.match(/^\\+\d{8,}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid number");

$("#EditView").validate({
    rules: {
        phone_work: {
            fnType: true,
            minlength: 10
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe This

```
$.validator.addMethod('fnType', function(value, element) {
return value.match(/^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/);
},'Enter Valid  phone number');
```

[Click Here for more information](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s03.html)

Answer (score 2):

An internation phone number can be checked like this:

```
/^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/
```

explanation:

```
^         # Assert position at the beginning of the string.
\+        # Match a literal "+" character.
(?:       # Group but don't capture:
[0-9]     # Match a digit.
\x20      # Match a space character
?         # between zero and one time.
)         # End the noncapturing group.
{6,14}    # Repeat the group between 6 and 14 times.
[0-9]     # Match a digit.
$         # Assert position at the end of the string.
```